# How can I directly open a file on the Web in a normal application?

Tags: macos, finder, websites

Suppose there is a file on the web such as:

```
http://www.example.com/something.txt
```

I know that I can read it in any number of browsers, or that I can download it using any number of techniques and open it locally.

I also know that in some cases I can connect using Web DAV, though that’s not always possible.

Is there a way that I can open a file directly from within an application such as a text editor? I don’t expect to be able to save it, so it would probably appear as a read-only file.

I’d be happy with a solution which involves MacFuse.

Comment: Why? Just save the page as .webarchive and then open it in a text editor, such as Textmate. If you open a webpage in an application, then the application **is** a web browser.

Comment: @njboot I know that I can download it using any number of techniques and open it locally. The file I used in the example was a text file. I asked whether it is possible to open such a file directly.

Comment: Unless an app specifically supports HTTP, FTP, etc. No. If someone implemented IP protocols as a mountable file system, maybe but I have not heard of that. The closest you will likely come is to assign file types you want (EG .TXT, .DOC, etc.) to open from a web browser directly in the app of your choice rather than saving or opening directly in the browser.